# connected two people using peer to peer if they are on different networks

Tags: android, chat, p2p, multipeer-connectivity

I have seen one demo where I can connected 2 devices if they are on same network

but when I shift one of the device to data pack and keep another one on wifi.. they can not fined each other.

Can someone please help me to understand what is happening

and as well as how can I connected these 2 devices even if they are on different networks.

Please recommend any demo or tutorial where code is present .

Thanks

Comment: You can only open a direct connection if the device has an IP address that is reachable from the other device.

Comment: Hi Henry could you please share some demo or any code sample you have ?